# How to make a rewrite of this function

Tags: python

I am learning Python, and I created 2 functions cutting:

```
def cutting_2(words):
    return [set(w) for w in words]    

cutting_2(['sed','hi'])
```

Perfect answer:

```
[{'d', 'e', 's'}, {'h', 'i'}]
```

But, when I tried to reformulate it, it did not work.

```
def cutting_1(words):
#everything = {}    
    for w in words:
          a = [set(w)];
          #everything = everything.append(a)
    return (a)  
  
cutting_1(['bye','hi'])
```

Wrong output:

```
[{'h', 'i'}]
```

How can I fix the second one?

Comment: You reassign `a` at each iteration, so you only get the last thing.

Comment: Another way to write that is just `return list(map(set, word))`.

Comment: Also note that it is not `everything = everything.append(a)`.  That would be the same as `everything = None`.  It should be just `everything.append(a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning to `a` each time through the loop, rather than *appending* to the same list.

```
def cutting_1(words):
    a = []
    for w in words:
          a.append(set(w))
    return a
```

Your commented-out code was nearly correct; you just needed to initialize `everything` to be a list, not a set.